# Webpack bundle my js but that js wont work

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babel-loader

my webpack `sass-loader` works allright without problems (removed for this example)
my `babel-loader` compiles everything but that js wont work even when is imported into html.

My javascript function that is compiled by webpack that is not working ( there was more functions and jquery but is removed for example)

```
    // Get href for pagination
    function getHref(obj) {
      event.preventDefault()
      var url = window.location.href;
      paginationQueries = url.split("?")[1];
      paginationHref = obj.getAttribute("href");
      if (paginationQueries) {
        pageRefUrl = paginationHref + "?" + paginationQueries
      } else {
        pageRefUrl = paginationHref
      }
      window.location.href = pageRefUrl;
    }

console.log("TEST123") // THIS WORKS BUT ALL OTHER SCRIPTS WONT WHEN THEY ARE BUNDLED WITH WEBPACK)
```

My webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {

    entry: path.resolve(__dirname + '/public/src/js/adminMain.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/public/dist/'),
        filename: 'adminBundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },


        ]
    },
    plugins: [


    ]

};
```

My bundle.js (compiled javascript (that one function)

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, { enumerable: true, get: getter });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // define __esModule on exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.r = function(exports) {
/******/        if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/        }
/******/        Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // create a fake namespace object
/******/    // mode & 1: value is a module id, require it
/******/    // mode & 2: merge all properties of value into the ns
/******/    // mode & 4: return value when already ns object
/******/    // mode & 8|1: behave like require
/******/    __webpack_require__.t = function(value, mode) {
/******/        if(mode & 1) value = __webpack_require__(value);
/******/        if(mode & 8) return value;
/******/        if((mode & 4) && typeof value === 'object' && value && value.__esModule) return value;
/******/        var ns = Object.create(null);
/******/        __webpack_require__.r(ns);
/******/        Object.defineProperty(ns, 'default', { enumerable: true, value: value });
/******/        if(mode & 2 && typeof value != 'string') for(var key in value) __webpack_require__.d(ns, key, function(key) { return value[key]; }.bind(null, key));
/******/        return ns;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = "./public/src/js/adminMain.js");
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ({

/***/ "./public/src/js/adminMain.js":
/*!************************************!*\
  !*** ./public/src/js/adminMain.js ***!
  \************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

eval("// Get href for pagination\nfunction getHref(obj) {\n  event.preventDefault();\n  var url = window.location.href;\n  paginationQueries = url.split(\"?\")[1];\n  paginationHref = obj.getAttribute(\"href\");\n\n  if (paginationQueries) {\n    pageRefUrl = paginationHref + \"?\" + paginationQueries;\n  } else {\n    pageRefUrl = paginationHref;\n  }\n\n  window.location.href = pageRefUrl;\n}\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./public/src/js/adminMain.js?");

/***/ })

/******/ });
```

And my import in handlebars

```
<!-- CONTENT -->
<div class="main-content-container">
    {{{body}}}
</div>

<!-- Import Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/adminBundle.js"></script>
```

But basically any js bundled with webpack wont work. I can open it from website source code and is imported allright.

Even without babel loader it wont work.

// UPDATE

When i add

```
console.log("TEST123")
```

To my javascript file it works but all other scripts wont work when they are bundled with webpack.

Comment: I think I can't help you until you https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @TienDuong I tried to edit my question (removed some stuff that was not necessary). Not sure if is enough.

Comment: Your entry points to `entry: path.resolve(__dirname + '/public/src/js/adminMain.js'),` which is  just a single file. Are you importing/requireing rest of the scripts in this file? If you are not, then webpack has no way to know what scripts to import

Comment: @AdityaParab Yes i have everything in this file even import of jquery but its removed for now to make easier to detect problem. I dont know why but console.log works but all other scripts wont. I think i have some wrong configuration in webpack.

Comment: `ALL OTHER SCRIPTS WONT WHEN THEY ARE BUNDLED WITH WEBPACK` Which scripts? How and where do you import them?

Comment: @JurajJakubov I think it would be great if you could create a https://repl.it with your entire config.. It's hard to know whats going wrong with the information shared here :)

Comment: @AdityaParab Okay i am uploading it will take some time. Then i will share link.

Comment: @AdityaParab i can upload it in few hours. But i found out that function works like when i do x=5 and then some if statement to console log some value if x = 5 and different value if x = 4 it works it just doesnt save those variables for client its just like server available. So i cant print in chrome console that x but i can print it when is in my script. (i am not using frontend engine like react or angular only handlebars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its solved. I cant use variables and functions on client side (if understand correctly).
So basically i cant use `<a id="oki123"> onclick="getHref(this)"</>` but i need to use `$('#oki123').on('click', () => getHref...;` in javascript file.
Not sure if is normal behaviou of webpack but probably yes. Thanks to all people for help and time u lost on me. So stupid mistake...